# How to execute a publisher as last step in jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to execute the publisher in my jenkins plugin as the last step in a jenkins job even if there are more post build plugins configured after this plugin. Is there a way i can set this while building jenkins plugin?

Comment: Why is the order important?

Comment: The order is important to my plugin will use the files created by another plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can change order of build and postbuild steps [by dragging its](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10501). Click header of step in project configuration and drag it up or down

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alek. However, is there a possibility of handling it in the plugin code itself so that the user does not have the binding of maintaining the order of post build steps in the job configuration?